# Hi, I just wanted to know what is the difference between myDb.db and db.myDb in python sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, filenames

So, I was just looking for a tutorial for sqlite3 python. Some people use the database name with db.myDb, and others use myDb.db. Can anyone explain the difference between the format names?

Comment: They're just names. Completely irrelevant. I'm not sure that `db.myDb` makes much sense, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: To complement @Chris answer, you must note that file extensions do not determine the content of the file. As such, regardless of the name, your database file will still function. Windows does rely heavily on file extensions while Linux reads the few first bytes of the file, AKA magic number.

Comment: Files typically use a name+extension convention for naming. Extension+name isn't something I can say I've ever seen in the wild for files, but is similar to other resource naming conventions that start with the general category and go progressively more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter which file-extension a database has to its functionality. It is just a name, so reading and writing will work the same.

Most Operating-Systems use the extension to determin wich icon to show in a file-browser or with which application to open a specific file. So choosing the right file-extensions for your database improves your workflow.

Typical extensions for `sqlite3` are:

- `.sqlite`
- `.sqlite3`
- `.db`
- `.db3`
- `.sdb`
- `.s3db`